# Upgrading to ASP.NET Core 1.0.1 September update warning

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

The upgrade to `ASP.NET Core 1.0.1` seems to be simple based on this [official msdn blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/09/13/asp-net-core-sept-2016-patch/)

[Download](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download#tools) `.NET Core Installer 1.0.1`

Update the `project.json`

```
 "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.*",
```

and

```
 "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
```

However after making a change for the above line I get warnings

> Warning   NU1012  Dependency conflict. Project.Web 1.0.0 expected Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel >= 1.0.1 but received 1.0.0 Project.Web
>
> Warning    NU1007  Dependency specified was Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel >= 1.0.1 but ended up with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel 1.0.0.

I then decide I will rather use the Nuget package manager and update the packages through it.

but the upgrade for MVC fails and "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" stays v1.0.0

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0"
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
```

If I set  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" in the file to 1.0.1 I get the following warning

> Warning   NU1012  Dependency conflict. Project.Web 1.0.0 expected Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc >= 1.0.1 but received 1.0.0
> Warning   NU1007  Dependency specified was Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc >= 1.0.1 but ended up with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.0.0.

Why does Nuget package manager pick up 1.0.1 but fail in upgrading it?

Why are these warnings happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it by right clicking in the 'project.json' and selecting Sort Properties which changes the order. It seems the order is important.

Comment: same here, so weird